# How to get the Executable name of a window

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I try to get the name of executable name of all of my launched windows and my problem is that:

I use the method

```
UINT GetWindowModuleFileName(      
HWND hwnd,
LPTSTR lpszFileName,
UINT cchFileNameMax);
```

And I don't understand why it doesn't work.

Data which I have about a window are: 
-HWND AND PROCESSID

The error is:
e.g:

```
HWND: 00170628 
ProcessId: 2336        
WindowTitle: C:\test.cpp - Notepad++
GetWindowModuleFileName():  C:\test.exe

HWND: 00172138 
ProcessId: 2543        
WindowTitle: Firefox
GetWindowModuleFileName():  C:\test.exe

HWND: 00120358 
ProcessId: 2436        
WindowTitle: Mozilla Thunderbird
GetWindowModuleFileName():  C:\test.exe
```

Note: test.exe is the name of my executable file, but it is not the fullpath of Notepad++... and it make this for Mozilla Thunderbird too... I don't understand why

I use the function like this:

```
char filenameBuffer[4000];
if (GetWindowModuleFileName(hWnd, filenameBuffer, 4000) > 0)
{
    std::cout << "GetWindowModuleFileName(): " << filenameBuffer << std::endl;
}
```

Thank you for your response.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

The [`GetWindowModuleFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowmodulefilenamea) function works for windows in the current process only.

You have to do the following:

1. Retrieve the window's process with [`GetWindowThreadProcessId`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid).
2. Open the process with `PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION` and `PROCESS_VM_READ` access rights using [`OpenProcess`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess).
3. Use [`GetModuleFileNameEx`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/psapi/nf-psapi-getmodulefilenameexa) on the process handle.

If you really want to obtain the name of the module with which the window is registered (as opposed to the process executable), you can obtain the module handle with [`GetWindowLongPtr`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowlongptra) with `GWLP_HINSTANCE`. The module handle can then be passed to the aforementioned `GetModuleFileNameEx`.

#### Example:

```
TCHAR buffer[MAX_PATH] = {0};
DWORD dwProcId = 0; 

GetWindowThreadProcessId(hWnd, &dwProcId);   

HANDLE hProc = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION | PROCESS_VM_READ , FALSE, dwProcId);    
GetModuleFileName((HMODULE)hProc, buffer, MAX_PATH);
CloseHandle(hProc);
```

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd318087%28v=vs.85%29.aspx

Comment: @MartinBa, note that it brings dependency on oleacc.dll though.

Comment: Yeah. I was just reading through your answer and thought I'd drop that funntion too, as it was my first hit on the search engine.

Comment: Note that `PROCESS_VM_READ` requires the `SeDebugPrivilege` to be present and enabled in the user token.

Comment: Though OP didn't ask for it, I find it interesting enough to mention yet another method of determining the MODULE a HWND belongs to (UI0Detect is using this procedure): if the window isn't a dialog, get its window procedure (from the window class) and determine the module (by enumerating) into whose address range the procedure falls.

Comment: Right way to do it! However, if you are running your executable as a different user and trying to get the process name using "OpenProcess", it will throw "Access Denied". Any other way to achieve this in this scenario?

Comment: I found that GetWindowThreadProcessId may not return the Parent Process ID. You need to call OpenThread on this returned value, and then call GetProcessIdOfThread.

Comment: @DerekWade the parent process ID is written to the variable that you point at in the 2nd parameter of `GetWindowThreadProcessId()`. It is not returned in the function's return value, that returns the parent thread ID instead. This is documented behavior. There is no need to use `OpenThread()` and `GetProcessIdOfThread()`

Comment: @kla No need to enumerate modules. [`GetModuleHandleExW`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-getmodulehandleexw) with `GET_MODULE_HANDLE_EX_FLAG_FROM_ADDRESS` is all you need. Now clearly, this is as brittle as it gets. It's not like [`GWLP_WNDPROC`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowlongptrw) is in any way protected.

Answer (score 5):

Aaah. I read the MSDN page at the bottom.

From http://support.microsoft.com/?id=228469 ([archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20111207181330/http://support.microsoft.com/?id=228469)):

> GetWindowModuleFileName and GetModuleFileName correctly retrieve information about windows and modules in the calling process. In Windows 95 and 98, they return information about windows and modules in other processes. However, in Windows NT 4.0 and Windows 2000, since module handles are no longer shared by all processes as they were on Windows 95 and 98, these APIs do not return information about windows and modules in other processes.
>
> To get more information on Windows 2000, use the Process Status Helper set of APIs (known as PSAPI, see Psapi.h include file), available since Windows NT 4.0. APIs such as GetModuleFileNameEx and GetModuleBaseName offer equivalent functionality.

Try using [GetModuleFileNameEx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683198%28VS.85%29.aspx) instead.

Answer (score 3):

http://support.microsoft.com/?id=228469 ([archive.org link](https://web.archive.org/web/20111207181330/http://support.microsoft.com/?id=228469))

The executive summary is, `GetWindowModuleFileName()` doesn't work for windows in other processes in NT-based Windows.

Instead, you can use [`QueryFullProcessImageName()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winbase/nf-winbase-queryfullprocessimagenamea) once you have a handle to the process. You can get a handle to the process with [`OpenProcess()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/processthreadsapi/nf-processthreadsapi-openprocess), which you can use once you have a process id. You can get the process id from the HWND by using [`GetWindowThreadProcessId()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowthreadprocessid)

Comment: @drescherjm I added a link from archive.org

Answer (score 1):

This is an example of how get the name of executable that creates window, hope it can give you some ideas about:

```
    while(true)
    {
    Sleep(250);//reduce cpu usage
    CHAR __name[MAX_PATH];//name buffer
    HWND hwnd;//window handle
    DWORD pid;//process pid
    hwnd=FindWindow(NULL,NULL);//find any window
    PROCESSENTRY32 entry;//process structure containing info about processes
    entry.dwSize=sizeof(PROCESSENTRY32);
    HANDLE snapshot=CreateToolhelp32Snapshot(TH32CS_SNAPPROCESS,0);//get processes
    if(hwnd!=0)
    {
        GetWindowThreadProcessId(hwnd,&pid);//get found window pid
    }
    if (Process32First(snapshot,&entry)==TRUE)//start listing processes
    {
        while (Process32Next(snapshot,&entry)==TRUE)
        {
            if (stricmp(entry.szExeFile,"explorer.exe")==0)
            {
                if(pid!=entry.th32ProcessID)//if found window pid is explorers one, skip it
                {
                    HANDLE hProcess=OpenProcess(PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS,FALSE,pid);//open processusing PROCESS_ALL_ACCESS to get handle
                    if(hProcess!=NULL)
                    {
                        GetModuleFileNameEx(hProcess,NULL,__name,MAX_PATH);//get executable path
                        cout<<"Found: "<<__name<<endl;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

To use GetModuleFileNameEx() you probably will need to set linker settings to link library psapi. Also include psapi.h.

Comment: +1 to `CreateToolhelp32Snapshot`, the only method I've found that actually returns the exe file name for ALL active processes easily, unlike `OpenProcess` that often needs additional access rights.