# VC++ How do I get the name of the main program a window belongs to?

Tags: visual-c++

EXAMPLE TESTING ENVIRONMENT:

I placed two folders on my Windows Desktop, each with its own content of files and subfolders. One of the folders is named ALPHA, the other is named BRAVO. I double clicked on each of these folders, so I have these two Windows Explorer windows open on my screen.

I also started Microsoft Word and created a new empty document (named Document1). Then pressed Ctrl+N to create another empty document (named Document2). So I have two Word windows open too.

I launched Firefox and navigated to bluepaint.com, then opened another browser window and navigated to yellowsand.org, so I also have two Firefox windows on my screen.

CODE:

Then in my Windows app (VS2019 Community) I capture the mouse button UP events and do something like this ...

```
TCHAR msg_tchar[256];
HWND wh_parent_window;  // parent_window or owner_window
const unsigned int max_wintitle_length = 256;
TCHAR window_title_string[max_wintitle_length];
HWND wh_current_window = GetForegroundWindow();
GetWindowText(wh_current_window, window_title_string, (max_wintitle_length-1));
StringCchPrintf(msg_tchar, 255, _T("--NewWindow: \"%s\"\r\n"), window_title_string);
printToLogfile(msg_tchar);
if ((wh_parent_window = GetWindow(wh_current_window, GW_OWNER)) != NULL) {
    GetWindowText(wh_parent_window, window_title_string, (max_wintitle_length-1));
    StringCchPrintf(msg_tchar, 255, _T("ownerWindow: \"%s\"\r\n"), window_title_string);
    printToLogfile(msg_tchar);
} //// if getOwnerWindow
if ((wh_parent_window = GetAncestor(wh_current_window, GA_PARENT)) != NULL) {
    GetWindowText(wh_parent_window, window_title_string, (max_wintitle_length-1));
    StringCchPrintf(msg_tchar, 255, _T("parentWindow: \"%s\"\r\n"), window_title_string);
    printToLogfile(msg_tchar);
} //// if getParendWindow
```

It compiles and runs fine, and does what I told it to do. Clicking through the windows on my screen I get the below output.

```
--NewWindow: "Yellow Sand Beach informational portal - Mozilla Firefox"
parentWindow: ""
--NewWindow: "Categories of blue paints - Mozilla Firefox"
parentWindow: ""
--NewWindow: "Document2 - Word"
parentWindow: ""
--NewWindow: "Document1 - Word"
parentWindow: ""
--NewWindow: "ALPHA"
parentWindow: ""
--NewWindow: "BRAVO"
parentWindow: ""
```

Apparently, no OwnerWindow lines. Which I do not care much about.
BUT what I do care about is WHAT APPLICATION these windows belong to. And it seems that I am on the wrong track with this, as I was hoping to get the main application name of each window. So for ALPHA and BRAVO I would like to get something like "**Windows Explorer**" or "**explorer.exe**", for the documents I would like to get something like "**Microsoft Office 2019**" or "**Microsoft Word**" or "**word.exe**", and for the webpage windows I would like to get something like "**firefox.exe**" or "**Firefox**" or "**Mozilla Firefox**". *Yes, I can see that Firefox and Word can be extracted from their window titles, but that does not work for ALPHA and BRAVO and for windows of other applications.*
So **insted of the window title, how do I get to the parent application name or the owning executable name?**

I am more than happy to read the documentation, I just do not know what function name to look for. A nudge into the right direction would be appreciated.

Comment: You may be looking for [`GetWindowModuleFileName`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-getwindowmodulefilenamew)

Comment: @IgorTandetnik excellent suggestion. GetWindowModuleFileName looks very promising. Unfortunately it returns 0 (and and empty string) for every single one of my window handles. Thus proves not useful in practice. :-(

Comment: Never mind. Apparently `GetWindowModuleFileName` only works for windows in the current process. See [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397578/how-to-get-the-executable-name-of-a-window)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the Executable name of a window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2397578/how-to-get-the-executable-name-of-a-window)

Comment: Yes, I also found that exact same article after looking into GetWindowModuleFileName. I will play around with the suggested solutions and see how far I can get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Igor's kick in the right direction, I wrote the below function and it serves the purpose I was looking for.

```
bool queryEXEnameOfWindow(HWND p_window_handle, std::wstring& p_exe_path) {
    TCHAR tmp_path_str[MAX_PATH] = {0};
    DWORD tmp_processID = 0;
    DWORD tmp_length = MAX_PATH-1;
    GetWindowThreadProcessId(p_window_handle, &tmp_processID);
    HANDLE processHandle = OpenProcess(PROCESS_QUERY_INFORMATION|PROCESS_VM_READ, FALSE, tmp_processID);
    BOOL tmp_result = QueryFullProcessImageName(processHandle, 0, tmp_path_str, &tmp_length);
    CloseHandle(processHandle);
    if (tmp_result) {
        p_exe_path = tmp_path_str;
        return true;
    } //// if
    return false;
} //// funcDef
```

Results returned in the **wstring** are like:

```
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\WINWORD.EXE
C:\Program Files\Firefox\firefox.exe
C:\Windows\explorer.exe
C:\Program Files\Microsoft Office\root\Office16\EXCEL.EXE
C:\Program Files\LibreOffice\program\soffice.bin
```